# How to send various data from android to php

Tags: php, android

Good morning I'm doing an application in android studio I'm using php to make my connection to the MYSQL database.

But when I make a query with a single argument to my database it works, but I made a modification to send two arguments and it does not work, since I validated my php and the query runs fine, but ** Android ** indicates error when executing my program, I'm looking for what the error may be but I have not found the reason why it is not executed properly

**android**

```js
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

  Spinner opciones;
  Button Consultar;
  EditText Cons;
  JSONArray ja;
  Tabla_Consulta tabla;
  LinearLayout linearLayout;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    opciones = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Consultar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_consultar);
    Cons = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Consulta);
    tabla = new Tabla_Consulta(this, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla));

    ArrayAdapter < CharSequence > adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Opc, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.preference_category);
    opciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    Consultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        String selec = opciones.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String selec1 = Cons.getText().toString();

        Consulta("http://10.0.2.2/Libro_Titulo.php?eje=" + opciones.getSelectedItem().toString() + "&" + "Tit=" + Cons.getText().toString());
        //Consulta("http://10.0.2.2/Biblioteca/Libro_Id.php?ide="+Cons.getText().toString());
        //     Log.d("query",   );
        Log.d("query", selec + " " + Cons.getText().toString());
        Log.d("query", selec + " " + selec1);

      }
    });
  }

  private void Consulta(String URL) {
    Log.i("conexion", URL);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener < String > () { //EL ERROR ESTA EN ESTA LINEA

      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
        int j = 1;
        Log.d("reponse", response);
        try {

          ja = new JSONArray(response);
          tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.Opciones);

          for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = c.getString("Id");
            String Titulo = c.getString("Titulo");
            String Autor = c.getString("Autor");
            String Editorial = c.getString("Editorial");
            String Facultad = c.getString("Facultad");
            String Reserva = c.getString("Reserva");

            if (Reserva.equals("0")) {
              Reserva = Reserva.replace("0", "Libre");
            } else if (Reserva.equals("1")) {
              Reserva = Reserva.replace("1", "Reserva");
            }

            ArrayList < String > elementos = new ArrayList < String > ();

            elementos.add(Integer.toString(j));
            elementos.add(id);
            elementos.add(Titulo);
            elementos.add(Autor);
            elementos.add(Editorial);
            elementos.add(Facultad);
            elementos.add(Reserva);
            elementos.add("BUTTON");
            tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
            j++;
          }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override

      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

      }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
  }
}
```

**Error**

> 04-17 15:31:01.276 11093-11238/com.example.ferney.bibliotecacur E/Volley: [429] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://10.0.2.2/Libro_Titulo.php?Consolu=Id&Tit=1

**PHP**

```js
< ? php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
include('Conectar.php');
$Tit = $_GET["Tit"];
$eje=$_GET["eje"];  // para solo un archivo
$rawdata = array(); //creamos un array

if ($resultset = getSQLResultSet("SELECT * FROM `tbl_libro` WHERE $Consolu='$Tit'")) {

  
  $rawdata = array(); //creamos un array
  $i = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset)) {       
    $rawdata[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
  }

  echo json_encode($rawdata);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check Whether you had put your **Server OnLine**
2. Verify the **URL** that you had Requested is **Correct**.
3. **Test the Web Service** is Working Correctly using **[PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/)** or **[Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)**
4. If you are using Emulator use IP as 10.0.2.2 and if a real device is using use same network and use IP of the System
5. While testing if no problem exists check your volley request

Comment: the fault was that the address is wrong because it is missing where the project is
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another Method to send data to server using **org.apache.http**

```
      ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
      String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/Libro_Titulo.php?eje="+id;
      String json="";
      json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
```

for **makeServiceCall** visit the link below

[ServiceHandler.java](https://github.com/Jagrit-vishwa/Service-Handler/tree/master)